# Table with date, then next date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to generate a table with one date followed by the next date in the set, given some criteria.

Raw Data:

```
id       date
1     2000-01-01
1     2000-01-02
1     2000-01-04
1     2000-01-10
1     2000-01-14
1     2000-01-15
1     2000-01-16
1     2000-01-18
2     2000-02-01
2     2000-02-02
2     2000-02-04
2     2000-02-10
2     2000-02-14
2     2000-02-15
2     2000-02-16
2     2000-02-18
```

Would result in:

```
   id       date           date
    1     2000-01-01    2000-01-02
    1     2000-01-02    2000-01-04
    1     2000-01-04    2000-01-10
    1     2000-01-10    2000-01-14
    1     2000-01-14    2000-01-15
    1     2000-01-15    2000-01-16
    1     2000-01-16    2000-01-18
    1     2000-01-18    NULL
    2     2000-02-01    2000-02-02
    2     2000-02-02    2000-02-04
    2     2000-02-04    2000-02-10
    2     2000-02-10    2000-02-14
    2     2000-02-14    2000-02-15
    2     2000-02-15    2000-02-16
    2     2000-02-16    2000-02-18
    2     2000-02-18    NULL
```

I know I have to use a self join, but I don't know how to return the sequentially next largest value, given that specific id. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you could just use the `lead()` function.  In MySQL, the easiest way is probably a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.date
        from rawdata t2
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.date > t.date
        order by t2.date
        limit 1
       ) as next_date
from rawdata t;
```

Comment: and order and limit the subquery to 1 row? add `order by t2.date limit 1` I think

Comment: This appears to be only returning the max from an id range, rather than literally just the next highest date value.

Comment: @TomKrakov . . . That `desc` should have been `asc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [date + interval 1 day] if it is a mysql or postgresql DB

For example:

```
select t.id, t.date, t.date + interval 1 days as date 2 from rawdata t;
```

For oracle you could do something like this:

```
select t.id , t.date, TO_DATE(t.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1 from rawdata t;
```

Comment: The difference in the date varies though, which is why I wouldn't be able to add a standard 1 day.